# Python: Keyboard event listener outside of command line

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, keylistener

I have a script in Python 3 that controls the cursor, it moves and clicks it. So when I run this script I can't do anything inside of the command line because it clicks out of the command line and I have no control under the cursor.

Is it possible to listen key presses outside of the command line? E.g.: I press the ESC button and the script terminates.

Answer (score 0):

## you can use pynput

http://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```